# Cannot close interstitial ad on InMobi Android SDK

Tags: android, webview, inmobi

I am using InMobi 5.2.1 android SDK for interstitial ads...

The ads are loading fine... However when the user clicks on the ad (to open the web browser), and goes back quickly, sometimes the ads are left open with no way to close it.

Clicking on the X does not seem to work, nor the back button..

When clicking on the back button I get the following error log:

*Unimplemented WebView method onKeyDown called from: android.webkit.WebView.onKeyDown(WebView.java:2310)*

I've tested this on 2 lollipop devices with the same issue.

Any clues?